# How can I use double quotes in a string without Internet Explorer modifying them?

Tags: javascript, string, internet-explorer

I am generating a complex string for an api search query from Sharepoint. I need to concatenate double quotes to the string and use the \ character to escape them.

```
if ($("#ddlPais option:selected").val() > 0) {
  url+= "RefinableString03: \"" + $("#ddlPais option:selected").text() + "\" ,";
}
```

The problem is that internet explorer generates the string in the variable with \". 
Since I am using the string variable in an AJAX request to the api search of Sharepoint, the query fails.

What can I do so that Internet Explorer does not change the " by \" in the variable?

PD: It's an internet explorer bug. I've tried with Chrome and the escape character \" works fine and in the variable leaves only the double quote.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to show your code.

Comment: The problem is in that code snippet. the string you should generate is RefinableString03: "valueX" but instead internet explorer generates RefinableString03: \ "valueX \". This causes the AJAX request to fail.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you can just use `$("#ddlPais").val()`, you don't need `option:selected`.

Comment: The problem is most likely with how you're using the `url` variable, I doubt IE is changing the string itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem. To solve it before making the ajax call, I execute the encodeURIComponent function that encodes the entire url of the ajax request and thus avoids the problems that were causing me double quotes. I post it in case someone has a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

What version of IE are you using? I test in my [IE 11 version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4gka.png) 11.116.18362.0 and the escape character [works well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyPa3.png). You could check [my demo code](https://jsfiddle.net/yuzhou0602/0d3vaek2/) in IE.

Besides, you could do it without escape character. Using single quotes to enclose the variable then you could use double quotes directly in the string. You could check the below code as a workaround:

```js
var url = "";
if ($("#ddlPais option:selected").val() > 0) {
  url += 'RefinableString03: "' + $("#ddlPais option:selected").text() + '" ,';
}
console.log(url);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddlPais">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">valueX</option>
  <option value="2">valueY</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The version I have is ie11 11.885.17134.0. 
I have already tried with single quotes but in the string variable behind IE adds the escape character \. That is, if I print the value of the variable, it prints it correctly with double quotes, but when inspecting the variable and checking its value before making the AJAX call, it adds the escape characters \ to the double quotes.

Comment: Could you please provide [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? So that we can test it in our sides and have a better understanding of the issue. The code snippet you provide doesn't show how it makes AJAX call and we can't reproduce the issue with only the above code. Thanks for your understanding.